# WorkFlow start only after event receiver ItemUpdated finish

Tags: sharepoint, workflow, sharepoint-workflow, eventreceiver

In workflow i need to send email with field which i update in event receiver ItemUpdated method
but some times workflow finishes first and send empty email, sometimes it works fine. How to be sure that workflow start **only** after this item  ItemUpdated method finished?

```
  public override void ItemUpdated(SPItemEventProperties properties)
        {
            base.ItemUpdated(properties);
            this.EventFiringEnabled = false;
            ListsEventReceiverHandlers.ItemUpdated(properties);
            this.EventFiringEnabled = true;
        }
```

that's my event receiver. In ListsEventReceiverHandlers.ItemUpdated(properties); i change some fields and want send changes be work flow< which starts as **parallel**

Comment: Does the Workflow start when an Item is created within a list. Could you show us some of your code?

Comment: i'm talking just about updating. With creating no problem